# Travis CI Enterprise: `travis encrypt` after successful login responds `not logged in, please run travis login --pro`

Tags: travis-ci

On my Travis CI **enterprise** setup, when I [use the Travis CLI to encrypt a password](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/), it complains that I'm not logged in, although I logged in successfully just before.

```
$ travis login -e https://travis-ci.my-company.corp/api
We need your GitHub login to identify you.
This information will not be sent to Travis CI, only to github.my-company.corp.
The password will not be displayed.

Try running with --github-token or --auto if you don't want to enter your password anyway.

Username: itsme
Password for itsme: ********
Successfully logged in as itsme!

$ travis encrypt 
not logged in, please run travis login --pro
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a default endpoint for the [Travis CLI](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/) solved this for me:

```
travis endpoint --set-default --api-endpoint https://travis-ci.my-company.corp/api
travis login
travis encrypt "escaped_password" --add deploy.password
```

While you're here, as a side note: When using `travis encrypt`, remember to [escape special characters](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/#Note-on-escaping-certain-symbols) in your password, because they'll be evaluated by `bash` in the build environment...